# How to add the friend with checkbox in android

Tags: android, checkbox

Hi In the below code I am using custom adapter to display the name with image and checkbox.Now,My problem is based on friend position I want to add with checkbox.

My layout like this:

image friendname with checkbox

Now, I want based on friend postion I want to return the checkbox is added to friend or not.suppose if I am selecting the username:user1 this one got checked.then I want to return username with checked postion for that I am using listview.

**java**

```
private class FriendListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {       
    class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        ImageView icon;
        CheckBox check1;                                                
    }
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Bitmap mOnlineIcon;
    private Bitmap mOfflineIcon;            
    private FriendInfo[] friends = null;

    public FriendListAdapter(Context context) {
        super();                
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);    
        mOnlineIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.greenstar);
            mOfflineIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.redstar);

    }

    public void setFriendList(FriendInfo[] friends)
    {
        this.friends = friends;             
    }


    public int getCount() {         
        return friends.length;
    }


    public FriendInfo getItem(int position) {               
        return friends[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {    
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {               
        final ViewHolder holder;    

        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grouplist, null);                      
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.check1 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);                                    
            convertView.setTag(holder);                 
        } else {                    
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(friends[position].userName);
        holder.icon.setImageBitmap(friends[position].status == STATUS.ONLINE ? mOnlineIcon : mOfflineIcon);
        holder.check1.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);              
        holder.check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                checkBoxState[position] = isChecked;

            }    
        });                             
        return convertView;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 holder.check1.setTag(getItem(position));
```

to set a tag with each row and yoju can later on check the tag by using

```
 int position = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
```

this will return the position

Comment: Hi Neha Shukla above code I wrote that one where shall i add

Comment: `holder.check1.setTag(getItem(position));` this should be added after ` holder.check1.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);`  and to get the position `int position = (Integer) buttonView.getTag(); ` add this code in             `public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                checkBoxState[position] = isChecked;

            }  `  
this function×An error occurred during comment submission×An error occurred during comment submission×An error occurred during comment submission

Comment: this function×An error occurred during comment submission

Comment: `holder.check1.setTag(getItem(position));` this should be added after `holder.check1.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);` and to get the position `int position = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();` add this code inside this function `public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) { checkBoxState[position] = isChecked; }`

Comment: holder.check1.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);

Comment: holder.check1.setTag(getItem(position)); after this line I was added

Comment: it giving when i was clicking the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

```
 holder.text.setText(friends[position].userName);
    holder.icon.setImageBitmap(friends[position].status == STATUS.ONLINE ? mOnlineIcon : mOfflineIcon);
    holder.check1.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]); 
    holder.check1.setTag(position);     
    holder.check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            int position = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();



            checkBoxState[position] = isChecked;

        }    
    });
```

Comment: holder.check1.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]); this line giving  error

Comment: if u want to check the checkbox i.e if you want to keep a tick mark then change the code as `holder.check1.setChecked(true);` and if u want to keep it unchecked then add `holder.check1.setChecked(false);`